# Failed ngfor when fetching data using http angular2

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, ngfor

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/index/home. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

client runs in 8000

rest service runs in 8080 and the service has @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000/")

but still not working

Comment: Obviously the server doesn's serve rhe URL you try to fetch.

Comment: i have checked with the rest client and i do get the response back. It is with the angular2 side, which i'm not sure where i'm making mistake

Comment: this is the error
 16.04.24 14:55:22 404 GET /
[1]             <section class="left_side">
[1]                     <article>
[1]                             <div class="div_home">
[1]                                     <div class="div_homeIndxPartition">
[1]                                             <div class="div_IndxPartition" *ngFor="
[1] 16.04.24 14:55:22 200 GET /app/equity/equityIndexConstituents.component.js.map

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message (except the `404`).

Comment: Can you try to format the error message properly (wrapping in backticks "`"). Please edit your question and add the error message there. Please check again this is exactly the error message. AFAIR a 404 shows also the URL that actually failed. Your comment above doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: when it tried to render the the loop the codes takes the each values from the list (ex: #index of indexes), which were it is failing. I dont see it is hitting the server even after adding the cross origin option in the server side

Comment: Looks like project configuration issue to me. I can't help you with this because I only use Dart myself and don't know about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```